# Is $\frac{x}{2}$ an algebraic fraction? If yes, isn't it improper? Then how to turn it proper?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

According to [Wikipedia on algebraic fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_fraction), $\frac{x}{2}$ seems an algebraic fraction.  Then by definition, as the degree of the numerator $1$ ($x^1$) is larger than the degree of the denominator $0$ ($x^0$), it is an *improper* algebraic fraction.  Now how can I turn it to a *proper* one?  Long division gives either $x - \frac{x}{2}$, $x - x + \frac{x}{2}$, $x - x + x - \frac{x}{2}$, $x - x + x - x + \frac{x}{2}$, ..., which suggests impossibility.  Should we exclude $\frac{x}{2}$ as an algebraic fraction?

Comment: It's not $\frac{x}{2}$; it's $\frac{1}{2}x$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks for the comment.  Do you mind expanding it into an answer, with proper evidence (say, citation) to support your answer?

Comment: I've never heard of proper or improper fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  I didn't see any explicit mention of whether a rational function with constant denominator should be considered improper.  If you apply the strict definition then it would seem to be.

But I think there is a way out.  Quoting from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_fraction) you linked to:

> Any improper rational fraction can be expressed as the sum of a polynomial (possibly constant) and a proper rational fraction.

In this case we have
$$
    \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}x
$$
So the “polynomial part” of $\frac{x}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{2}x$, and the “proper rational fraction part” is $0$.

Comment: I think it is acceptable to call a polynomial an improper rational function since it plays the same role as the integer part of an improper fraction.

Comment: I think you both meant to type "rational _fraction_".